# Post from Console App to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to perform a POST action to MVC controller like so:

```
        string payload = "hello";
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var str = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(payload), Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52653/");
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync("Home/TestPost", str).Result;
        }
```

MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestPost(string value)
{
    var result = value;
    return Content("hello");
}
```

When I debug I see the breakpoint hit in the controller but "value" param is null.

Is this even possible? can objects be sent this way as well? ie (Person)?

Comment: Have you tried just posting a string and not `StringContent`?

Comment: you can not use HttpClient.PostAsync(string)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method.

```
var str = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
```

The serialized JSON string would look like:

```
{"payload":"hello"}
```

Also change

```
public ActionResult TestPost(string value)
```

TO

```
public ActionResult TestPost(string payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the FromBody attribute, that should work.

As @maccettura pointed out, you must include the proper namespace for this to work

```
using System.Web.Http;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestPost([FromBody]string value)
{
    var result = value;
    return Content("hello");
}
```

Another method is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> TestPost(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var requestString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return requestString;
}
```

Comment: FromBody namespace not found in mvc

Comment: You have to use `using System.Web.Http;`

Comment: FromBody can not be found

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http(v=vs.118).aspx note the section FromBodyAttribute Class.